# IndexedDB - How to create and use simple and complex IDBIndex keyPaths?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, indexeddb

I want to create and use two IndexedDB indices, one with a simple keyPath and the other with a complex keyPath. Although the creation is successful in every browser I tried, the indices do not seem to be filled correctly in most.

The **procedure** I'm using (self-contained test case at the end of the question) is:

1. Creation of an indexedDB with a single store with `{ keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true }`.
2. Creation of two indices: the first index is created with `keyPath: 'id'` and `{ unique: false, multiEntry: false }`. The second index is created with `keyPath: ['id', 'name']` and `{ unique: false, multiEntry: false }`.
3. Addition of some (19) objects to the store, all with a `name` attribute present.
4. Calling [`IDBIndex.count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/count) on both indices.

The **expectation** was that both calls of `IDBIndex.count` would return the total number of objects present in the store (19). Depending on the browser, this may or may not happen:

- Safari    10.0.3          **simple: 19, complex: 19**
- Chrome    57.0.2987.98    **simple: 19, complex: 0**
- Opera     43.0.2442.1144  **simple: 19, complex: 0**
- IE        11.953.14393.0  **simple: 0, complex: 0**
- Edge      38.14393.0.0    **simple: 0, complex: 0**
- Firefox   54.0a2          **simple: 0, complex: 0**

If I change the creation of the indices from `{ unique: false, multiEntry: false }` to just `{ unique: false }` the behaviour remains the same in every browser.

If I change the creation of the complex index from `['id', 'name']` to the ([according to the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-key-path)) equivalent `id.name`, Safari changes behaviour to **simple: 19, complex: 0**¹, the others remain the same.

If I change the creation of the complex index from `'id'` index to `['id']`, Safari still returns **simple: 19, complex: 0**, every other browser returns **simple: 0, complex: 0**.

What am I doing wrong? How do I create multi-attribute indices?

(I'm currently using the following self-contained example for testing, which will not work on stackoverflow due to it using indexedDB)

```js
var deleteRequest = indexedDB.deleteDatabase('test-db');
deleteRequest.onerror = deleteRequest.onblocked = deleteRequest.onsuccess = function () {
 console.log('Database deleted', arguments);
 var openRequest = indexedDB.open('test-db');
 openRequest.onerror = function (errorEvent) { console.log('open error', errorEvent); };
 openRequest.onblocked = function (blockedEvent) { console.log('open blocked', blockedEvent); };
 openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (upgradeEvent) {
  console.log('Database opened');
  var database = upgradeEvent.target.result;
  var store = database.createObjectStore('sochrastic', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
  store.createIndex('index_name', ['id', 'name'], { unique: false, multiEntry: false });
  store.createIndex('index_id', 'id', { unique: false, multiEntry: false });
 };
 openRequest.onsuccess = function (successEvent) {
  console.log('Indices created');
  successEvent.target.result.close();
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open('test-db');
  openRequest.onerror = function (errorEvent) { console.log('open error', errorEvent); };
  openRequest.onblocked = function (blockedEvent) { console.log('open blocked', blockedEvent); };
  openRequest.onsuccess = function (upgradeEvent) {
   console.log('Database opened');
   var database = upgradeEvent.target.result;
   var transaction = database.transaction('sochrastic', 'readwrite');
   var store = transaction.objectStore('sochrastic');
   store.add({ name: 'druk', badjorance: 'animal' });
   store.add({ name: 'druk', badjorance: 'beast' });
   store.add({ name: 'druk', badjorance: 'canal' });
   store.add({ name: 'myke', badjorance: 'dice' });
   store.add({ name: 'myke', badjorance: 'evergreen' });
   store.add({ name: 'myke', badjorance: 'fake' });
   store.add({ name: 'myke', badjorance: 'game' });
   store.add({ name: 'grey', badjorance: 'honor' });
   store.add({ name: 'grey', badjorance: 'incognito' });
   store.add({ name: 'grey', badjorance: 'joke' });
   store.add({ name: 'grey', badjorance: 'key' });
   store.add({ name: 'grey', badjorance: 'lemon' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'mast' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'nothing' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'opera' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'pear' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'quote' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'rodent' });
   store.add({ name: 'brady', badjorance: 'sunk' });

   database.close();
   var openRequest = indexedDB.open('test-db');
   openRequest.onerror = function (errorEvent) { console.log('open error', errorEvent); };
   openRequest.onblocked = function (blockedEvent) { console.log('open blocked', blockedEvent); };
   openRequest.onsuccess = function (successEvent) {
    console.log('Store filled');
    var database = successEvent.target.result;
    var transaction = database.transaction('sochrastic', 'readonly');
    var store = transaction.objectStore('sochrastic');
    var indexName = store.index('index_name');
    var nameCountRequest = indexName.count();
    nameCountRequest.onerror = function (errorEvent) { document.querySelector('#name-id-count').textContent = 'error'; console.log(errorEvent); };
    nameCountRequest.onblocked = function (blockedEvent) { document.querySelector('#name-id-count').textContent = 'blocked'; console.log(blockedEvent); };
    nameCountRequest.onsuccess = function (successEvent) { document.querySelector('#name-id-count').textContent = successEvent.target.result; console.log('name-id', successEvent.target.result); };

    var indexId = store.index('index_id');
    var idCountRequest = indexId.count();
    idCountRequest.onerror = function (errorEvent) { document.querySelector('#id-count').textContent = 'error'; console.log(errorEvent); };
    idCountRequest.onblocked = function (blockedEvent) { document.querySelector('#id-count').textContent = 'blocked'; console.log(blockedEvent); };
    idCountRequest.onsuccess = function (successEvent) { document.querySelector('#id-count').textContent = successEvent.target.result; console.log('id', successEvent.target.result); };
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>IndexedDB Indices</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>['id', 'name'] index result: <span id="name-id-count"></span></p>
 <p>['id'] index result: <span id="id-count"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE and Edge don't support complex indexes at all https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/indexeddbarraysandmultientrysupport/?q=indexeddb but you can use them in other browsers.

> If I change the creation of the complex index from ['id', 'name'] to the (according to the spec) equivalent id.name, Safari changes behaviour to simple: 19, complex: 0, the others remain the same.

Those aren't equivalent. `id.name` creates an index on a single value like `{id: {name: 'value'}}`, and `['id', 'name']` creates a compound index on two fields with those names like `{id: 1, name: 'value'}`.

Your indexes are failing because you're relying on the auto-generated primary key `id`. If you change `id` to `badjorance`, then your counts are as you expected, at least in Firefox and Chrome. (BTW, I didn't see any difference in those even in your original example, both browsers show 0s for both counts).

I guess some browsers evaluate the keyPath before adding the primary key to the object, and others after. As to which behavior is correct... it's too late at night for me to want to read the spec, but unless the spec is ambiguous, you might want to report bugs in the browsers that got it wrong. If I were a betting man, I'd guess that Safari is the one that's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the spec. And yes, that does seem to be it. The disparity between your test and mine seems to because I've actually tested with `id` and not `['id']`. I wonder if simple keyPaths are being evaluated before and complex ones before…